# access protected inherited member with pointer to base class

Tags: c++

Can someone explain why this code doesn't work.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(void){}
    virtual ~A(void){}
protected:
    A* parent;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(void){parent = new B;}
    ~B(void){delete parent;}
protected:
    int a;
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    C(void){}
    virtual ~C(void){}
    void f(void){ ((B*)parent)->a; }
};
```

How is it possible that `C` isn't able to access members of `B`?

If I convert `parent` to a `C*` in stead of a `B*` it works fine. But I don't want users to take any unnecessary risks. Is there a cleaner way access `a`?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd think that code would crash upon first creation of a `C` instance because the default constructor creates another instance as parent which then creates another instance which then creates...

Comment: @Axel: This is just a simplified version of the real code of course. But I updated the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 8):

From an object of the `C` class, you can access protected members of `B`, but only if they're part of some object of class `C` (maybe yours, maybe not). In other words, to access `a` from `C`, you need a pointer (or a reference) to `C`. This is what the `protected` modifier means.

The reason for this is the following. The `((B*)parent)` pointer may point to some other subclass of `B`, completely different from `C`, and that subclass may have the `a` member inaccessible.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Without restructuring the code, any suggestions I make are going to be quite hacky. You may 1) cast `parent` to `C*`, as you suggested or 2) make `B::a` publicly accessible (probably via some method) or 3) make `C` a friend class of `B`. To make up a more elegant solution, one would have to know more about your actual code (classes `A`, `B` and `C` just don't provide enough context to go).

Comment: I am talking about example of: pointer may point to some other subclass of B, completely different from C, and that subclass may have the a member inaccessible.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. The example is `parent` being an instance of `class D : public B { private: using B::a; };`. The `a` member is inaccessible through `D`, but it is through `B`. It's a strange design, I know, but the point here is not the (in)accessibility, not really. It's rather a point of `B::a` changing its meaning as it gets inherited by subclasses. E.g. if you've got `class E : public B {};`, then within `E` the `a` member may be interpreted differently from the way it's interpreted within `B`.

Comment: I don't quite get the question. `((B*)parent)` is a pointer to `B` that can point to an instance of some `D`. The fact that there's no `D` in you code doesn't matter: it can be declared elsewhere - or loaded at runtime from a dynamic library, for that matter. The point is, to access an inherited protected member from `C`, you need a pointer to `C`. With a pointer to `B`, there's no guarantee that it won't point to something that has semantics (or accessibility) of `B::a` changed.